# Publish an outsourced app - iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

I work in a government company that purchased the development(outsourced) of an iOS app and I was designated to publish at app store. What is the best way to receive this app from the developer and do it? Does he has to package(.app) and send to me?

Answer (score 0):

The developer should send you an `.xcarchive` of the build. Once you have the `.xcarchive`, you can use Xcode to publish to the store. Open Organizer (Xcode > Window > Organizer), select the `.xcarchive` and click "Upload to App Store". Xcode will walk you through a few steps to package the `.app` that's inside the `.xcarchive` into an ipa and start the upload process to iTunesConnect.

**Beforehand:** You will need to make sure you have the correct code signing certificates and provisioning profiles set up in your developer account. You will also need to create a record in iTunesConnect for the app to upload to.

Comment: Thanks, Jake. I'm gonna ask the developer for it!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this answer: [Is it possible to let somebody else upload and distribute my app in Apple's App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281246/is-it-possible-to-let-somebody-else-upload-and-distribute-my-app-in-apples-app)

In fact you have two options, also depending on your expertise and contract with the developers, but in the end you need a (company) developer account if you want that you are also listed as the developer of the app.

If that is not the case you should let the developers deploy the app to the appstore on behalf of your department.

IF you want to be also listed as developer of the app you have to do it like suggested in the link above, you create an account and add the external developer as a team member - but this will be more complicated.

Comment: Nice, here we have a company account. I asked the developer to send the .xcarchive and do the steps Jake suggested.